# Why are we using greater than symbol in CSS when we apply properties of flex and grid?

Tags: html, css

Why are we using the "greater than" symbol in CSS when we implement properties of flex and grid? I've given a sample code below:

```
.flex-item > div {}
```

Help me, please.

Comment: It’s a concatenation element. It means that the rule applies to any div inside the element with class flex-item. It’s css wide, not only for flex or grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` symbol isn't related to flex but it's part of CSS selector syntax. It is used to **select immediate children**. Here's an example:

```
<div class='first'>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="third">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="third">...</div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Now

```
.first > div {
}
```

will only apply to the divs with `second` class, since `third` isn't immediate children of `first`.

Answer (score 1):

This means 'every div that's a child of flex-item'

`>` is used to select the element with a specific parent.

Comment: Thank you @Akshay kn :D